# how to install laravel with error connection refused

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, composer-php, localhost

How to solve this error while installing Laravel and creating project:-

```bash
$ composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravelproject
Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./laravelproject"

In CurlDownloader.php line 365:

  curl error 7 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 56623: Connection refused
```

```
$ composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravelproject
```

I have tried it using the above command

Comment: Sounds like you are having networking issues - what have you tried to resolve them? Also, please do not tags that are not related to your problem. The current error message is not thrown by Laravel itself, nor is it related to [tag:localhost]